# Move a vector without C++11

Tags: c++

Let's say I have something like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    void Bar (std::vector <int> &vec) ;
    std::vector <int> m_vec ;
};

void Foo::Bar (std::vector <int> &vec)
{
    // Do stuff...

    m_vec = std::move (vec) ;
}
```

Is there any way, possibly with pointer trickery or `std::swap` that I would be able to simulate the `m_vec = std::move (vec) ;` line? Let's assume the `vec` being passed in was allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
void Bar(std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    m_vec.swap(vec);
    std::vector<int>().swap(vec);  // clear "vec"
}
```

Comment: The first swap does what is required. But why use swap the second time instead of `vec.clear()`?

Comment: the second swap is superfluous. In the constructor, m_vec already is a valid empty vector.

Comment: @Deduplicator If this function is called multiple times, then `m_vec` is no longer empty.

Comment: ok, but in this case you have the lines in the wrong order. Or don't you want exception safety for free?

Comment: @Deduplicator: `Bar` isn't a constructor. Since `vector::swap` cannot throw, the way to make this function offer the strong exception guarantee is to split the second line up. Create the new empty vector *before* the first swap, then swap it with `vec` afterwards. In practice you might find that creating an empty vector is nothrow too in your implementation (so the order is irrelevant since nothing can fail), but I don't think that's guaranteed.

Comment: It isn't guaranteed, and my edit did as you suggested already. Sorry for not being clearer with my comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator Exception safety is still something I'm learning about. If it means anything to you, I found your comment to be helpful.